# Laravel com Site + Cms + Intranet

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou criando um site que vai contemplar um cms e uma intranet. No CakePhp eu separava essas aplicações com Plugins, isto é, site na raiz do projeto/cake e plugins para os demais. Bem tranquilo, organizado e funcional

Como consigo fazer isso no Laravel? Não gostaria de deixar os controllers e models tudo misturado.

Vale ressaltar que estou iniciando agora no Laravel (5.X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja essa *vendor* que permite trabalhar no Laravel com HMVC [pingpong](https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules) que pode ser mais familiar a você. De todo modo, mesmo sem usar essa *vendor* que citei, vale a sua organização na hora de criar sua aplicação, se não quer misturar tudo, depende de como pensa na infraestrutura e o Laravel não obriga você a misturar tudo, talvez, tão pouco outro framework.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta William. Vou ver sobre essa vendor. Mas no caso consigo separar por pastas os models e controllers? Minha "organização" que digo é mais relacionado ao espaço físico e não lógico.